# roll back transaction using mysql in java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, rollback

I am inserting data into three table i.e.

```
Transaction
TransactionEntry
Payment
```

First I insert the data in **Transaction** , and then get **Transaction ID** and then insert data in **TransactionEntry**, after this inserting in **Payment**

Suppose in first two table, data inserted successfully. Then Server breakdown.

How can we Roll Back all the entries? can we control it programmatically or database has default feature to control this type of situation?

How to achieve consistency and  integrity?

Which framwork, In java , can control this type of situation?

**MySQL**  **Java EE**

Answer (score 4):

You need to disable autocommit and commit after your unit of work is done (or rollback when it failed).

This should be something like:

```
Connection con = ...; //set earlier
con.setAutoCommit(false);
...
try {
  //insert here
  ...
  con.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
  con.rollback();
  // other exception handling
}
```

Comment: Dear, I am using MVC. I have one controller that invoke three methods from services and each service has its on Connection? then how your suggested solution work?

Comment: I think you should put up another question and include this piece of information in your question. You could look into distributed transactions (XA), or the transaction management features of Spring.

Answer (score 2):

mysql supports transactions the normal way. Open transaction at the beginning and commit at the end, if something happens in the middle nothing will be posted.

Since you are using Java EE you have to investigate whether your java mysql client proposes or not built in statements. If not, use

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;

... statements ...

COMMIT;
```

Comment: -1, When using JDBC you should always use the `setAutoCommit(false)` method and the `commit()` or `rollback()` methods and not the native commands of the database. See documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html (_"Applications should not invoke SQL commands directly to change the connection's configuration when there is a JDBC method available."_)

Comment: I Investigate, In java connection.setAutoCommit(false); connection.commit(); and in exception connection.rollback(); I REFRESH THE PAGE AFTER MY COMMETNS BUT @MarkRotteveel ALREADY GAVE THE ANSWER ;)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, you are right, that's why i said IF j2ee doesn't provide built-in methods... :-)